how to profile file access in android or linux?
Android Runtime can profile the hot classes and methods when the apps running.
Can I profile the file accessing (read and write), let me know the hot file accesses, so I can optimization for these file accesses.
How can I do that?

by atrace pagecache  command, ftrace filesystem trace
